# From Day To Month: Calculating the average "trend" for the month

Tags: excel-formula, average

I have a table called **DayTable** that contains **Day** with a corresponding value, **Trend**. I have created a second table **MonthTable** with column **Month** and an empty column **Trend**. In each cell of the column **Trend**, I would like to calculate the average trend value for that month.

My initial plan was to create a formula that averages the **Trend** value if the month and year of the value in the **Month** column of the **MonthTable** equals the month and year of each day in the **DayTable**.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(DayTable[Trend],MONTH(DayTable[Day]),">="&MONTH([@Month]),YEAR(DayTable[Day]),">="&YEAR([@Month]))
```

This is my most recent formula that does not work.

I am interested if anyone has insight into making this formula work or could suggest a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should reconsider the structure of your data.

- I would have only ONE table with 2 main data series: DATE and TREND.
- Add a calculated column for MONTH, you can use =TEXT(cell,"mmm-yyyy")
- Summarize using Pivot.

Something like this: 
[new table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8MXp.png)

Hope this helps.